# Rename a file and save it as a another one

Tags: c

I'm trying to get a filename that exists at the beginning. After that I want to add `_blabla.txt` to the filename and create the another one.

Here the example. -->    `example.txt` (what I get)
Here the what I want. --> `example_blabla.txt` (what I want to create)

I tried to use `sprintf(filename, "%s%s", argv[1], "_blabla.txt")` but the created file's name is `example.txt_blabla.txt`.

How can I remove extension of first filename from the filename that I created ?

Here is my code:

```
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp2;
    char filename[300];
    
    if (argc != 2 || argv[1] == NULL) {
        printf(" You did not enter a file name! \n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    sprintf(filename, "%s%s", argv[1], "_blabla.txt");
    
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fp2 = fopen(filename, "w");
    
    return 0;
```

Comment: 1. Allocate a variable with memory for a new string that has enough bytes to store the filename without extension and with terminating zero byte. 2. Copy the filename without extension. 3. Set the zero terminating character. Or you can just write the zero terminating character at the place of dot in your original string in `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Append the following statements before and after your `sprintf()` call as follows:

```
int i;
char *pChar = NULL;
for (i = strlen(argv[1]) - 1; i >= 0: i--) {
    if (argv[1][i] == '.') {
       pChar = &argv[1][i];
       *pChar = '\0';
       break;
    }
}
sprintf(filename,"%s%s",argv[1],"_blabla.txt");
if (pChar != NULL)
   *pChar = '.';
```

Comment: `sprintf` is risky. Consider using `snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "%s%s", argv[1], "_blabla.txt");`. Also why do you strip all `.` from `argv[1]`? Finally the ending value of `i` is `-1`, so `argv[1][i] = '.';` has undefined behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie I forgot the ```break``` statement as I was only looking to replace the last occurrence of the ```.``` character. Edited my answer after you pointed it out!

Comment: @chqrlie As for the ```sprintf()``` thing, I merely used the function the OP used in the question as, I fear, this may be a homework question from the OP in which the instructor/teacher specifically "recommended" to use the primitive functions as they are not yet taught of buffer overflows.

Comment: @chqrlie Modified the answer again to fix the issue you mentioned!

Comment: I get your point about `sprintf`, but I prefer teaching better solutions directly. Teachers should not endorse `sprintf`, `gets`, ...

Comment: @chqrlie Fixed the issue, again! (I guess I am not feeling really sharp today!) As for your comment on ```pChar = strchr(argv[i], '.')```, it fails when the file is named something like ```abcd.efgh.txt```. The solution of utmost elegance would be to use the function ```PathCchRemoveExtension()``` in the WINAPI to resolve this, but, assuming the OP is a beginner, I doubt the OP is comfortable using the WINAPI just yet!

Comment: I was suggesting `pChar = strrchr(argv[i], '.')` (with an extra **r**) which does exactly what you need. Using a Windows API would not fit my definition of elegance as it would hamper portability and readability. There is no indication that the OP uses this OS and there is no reason to restrict the code.

Comment: The char string pointed to by `argv[]` are (typically) in readonly memory so modification will not work

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

- to locate the last `'.'` in the string, you can use the function `strrchr()` from `<string.h>`.
- to avoid undefined behavior on overlong strings, use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`.
- to copy a portion of a string with `snprintf`, use `%.*s` with an `int` argument before the string pointer.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp2;
    char filename[300];
    char *p;
    int pos;
    
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf(" You did not enter a file name!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    p = strrchr(argv[1], '.');
    if (p != NULL)
        pos = p - argv[1];
    else
        pos = strlen(argv[1]);

    // Using the %.*s precision field to limit the number of characters
    //  copied from `argv[1]`
    snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "%.*s_blabla.txt", pos, argv[1]);
    
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return 1;
    fp2 = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (fp2 == NULL)
        return 1;

    /* copy the file */

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. demonstrates a method to extract the root name from a filename then append a set of characters.
2. demonstrates how to inform the user when the command line parameter is missing.
3. does not perform a `stat()` to assure the source file actually exists, That is left to the OP to include.
4. properly checks for I/O errors
5. documents why each header file is included
6. suggest getting the length of the `argv[1]` parameter, add the length of `blabla.txt`, add 1, then use the VLA feature of C to appropriately size the array `filename[]`. Note: `strlen()` works well for obtaining the length of a NUL terminated char array

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // fopen(), fclose(), perror(), fprintf(), FILE
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>   // strrchr(), strcat()

int main( int argc, char (argv[] )
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp2;
    char filename[300];
    
    if (argc != 2 ) 
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s fileName\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    strcpy(filename, argv[1] );
    char *ptr = strrchr( filename, '.' );

    if( ptr )
    {
        *ptr = '\0';
    }

    strcat( filename,  "_blabla.txt");
    
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if( ! fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen for input file failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
  
    fp2 = fopen(filename, "w");
    if( ! fp2 )
    {
        perror( "fopen for output file failed" );
        fclose( fp1 );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    return 0;
}
```